In Rust, why can't I await an async_std::task::JoinHandle in a closure within the map method?
I learn Rust language with a book "Programming Rust 2nd Edition".
I wrote the codes for requesting many requests included chapter asynchronous programming as I wish.
use async_std::io::prelude::*;
use async_std::task;
use async_std::net;

async fn cheapo_request(host: &str, port: u16, path: &str) -> std::io::Result<String> {
    eprintln!("entering cheapo request: {} {} {}", host, port, path);

    let mut socket = net::TcpStream::connect((host, port)).await?;
    eprintln!("connect: {} {} {}", host, port, path);

    let request = format!("GET {} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n", path, host);

    socket.write_all(request.as_bytes()).await?;
    eprintln!("write_all: {} {} {}", host, port, path);
    socket.shutdown(net::Shutdown::Write)?;

    let mut response = String::new();

    socket.read_to_string(&mut response).await?;
    eprintln!("read_to_string: {} {} {}", host, port, path);

    Ok(response)
}

async fn many_requests(requests: Vec<(String, u16, String)>) -> Vec<std::io::Result<String>> {
    let handles = requests
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(host, port, path)| task::spawn_local(async move {
            cheapo_request(&host, port, &path).await
        }))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();


    handles
        .into_iter()
        .map(|h| async { h.await })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    /*
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for handle in handles {
        results.push(handle.await);
    }

    results
     */
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let requests = vec![
        ("www.naver.com".to_string(), 443, "/".to_string()),
        ("www.yahoo.net".to_string(), 443, "/".to_string()),
        ("www.google.com".to_string(), 443, "/".to_string()),
    ];

    let results = task::block_on(many_requests(requests));

    for result in results {
        match result {
            Ok(response) => println!("{}", response),
            Err(err) => eprintln!("error: {}", err),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

In the function many_requests, handles.into_iter().map(|h| async { h.await }).collect::<Vec<_>>() is my way, and wrapped codes up as note is book's way
I do not understand why my way generate an error "error[E0308]: mismatched types. expected Vec<Result<String, Error>>, found Vec<{async block@src\main.rs:41:18: 41:57}>".

You can't use h.await in map() because map() expects a sync closure, and .await is only available in an async function. Your attempt to cheat by wrapping await in an async { ... } block can't work because async gives you a Future, i.e. async { foo.await } is semantically the same as foo. For .await to work you need specialized version of map() that is aware of async. You've basically discovered the "colored function" problem.

You might also want to look into futures::future::join_all(), as shown in this answer.
